# What happens with current installs in Google Play when you raise minSdkVersion?

Tags: android

What happens to existing users with the app installed when minSdkVersion is raised and their SDK version is less than that?

Do they still get the update from Google Play with a subsequent crash? Or do they stop getting updates from Google Play?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Below happens on `minSdkVersion` change

1. On apk upload, **Google plays warns you** on minSdkVersion telling how many users will be affected.
2. Existing users lower than `minSdkVersion` **won't get update and cannot
   see app in PlayStore**
3. Existing users lower than `minSdkVersion`, if they uninstall, **cannot
   reinstall** the application.

*I suggest you use multiple apk option in PlayStore and continue to update your newer apk. Just keep the old one as it is.*

> For example, you can publish your application with one APK that
>   supports API levels 4 - 7 (Android 1.6 - 2.1)—using only APIs
>   available since API level 4 or lower—and another APK that supports API
>   levels 8 and above (Android 2.2+)—using APIs available since API level
>   8 or lower.

For more, read the android documentation on [multiple apk support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).

Comment: Here's a theoretical situation: Let's say you have an app with a minSDKVersion of 11 & which uses an Ad SDK v2.0.  And let's say you have a sizeable number of users with SDK version 11 devices using your app.  Then let's suppose a security vulnerability is found in v2.0 of that Ad SDK and you are told to update it otherwise it will be non-compliant and you run the risk of the app it being taken down.  You can't update it because the ad network has raised the minSDKVersion to 14 in v2.1 of their SDK and you can't keep the old one lest it be taken down.  How would one proceed?

Answer (score 7):

They will not get an update and it won't show up on Google Play for them any more. The version they have installed will remain on their device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guessed as much, but wanted to be sure.